# Services don't have MySQL Server. How to run it?

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-5.6

I need to run MySQL Server on a new for me laptop. There's Windows 7. And MySQL have been installed on it. In order to verify this, I opened the `Programs and Features` window and saw it there:

[Programs and Features screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x42Zm.jpg)

But when I go to the `Services` to run it, I don't find it. It's absent there:

[Services screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Fgr4.jpg)

It's very strange for me. Why MySQL is not among the services? How can I run it? It's installed on this station. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You may have not installed MySQL using the wizard or skipped that part.

You have [full installation instructions in order to add MySQL server as a Windows service on the reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/windows-start-service.html), basically:

- Ensure that MySQL is stopped (`mysqladmin shutdown`)
- Install the server as a service (`mysqld --install`), optionally setting a name for it

More details on the aforementioned manual page.